# Error 415 Unsupported Media Type for GET method

Tags: rest, mule, anypoint-studio, anypoint-platform

I'm currently working through the Mulesoft Mule 4 Fundamentals course and have deployed an application on Runtime Manager.

When I look in the logs of my application on Runtime Manager and the logs of Anypoint Studio I see the above "Unsupported Media Type" error when testing a GET HTTP request. I also get this error when testing in ARC.

When I look in the Mule debugger and then the payload in Anypoint Studio I see `mediaType = */* charset = UTF-8`

I thought that this does not need to be added for GET requests, so how do I get around this?

My RAML file:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: session-2

types:
  newsProperties: !include schemas/newsDataType.raml

/search:
  get:
    headers:
      Accept:
        default: application/json
    queryParameters:
      keyword:
        type: string
        minLength: 3
        maxLength: 10
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/json:
            example: !include examples/searchExample.raml
      400:
        body:
          application/json:
            example:
              {"message": "Search query too long"}
/news:
  post:
    queryParameters:
      country:
        required: false
    body:
      application/json:
        type: newsProperties
    responses:
      201:
        body:
          application/json:
            example: !include examples/searchExample.raml

/sportsNews:
  put:
    body:
      application/json:
        type: newsProperties
```

The header in the /search resource GET method has been added recently after searching online and trying a number of different solutions I've seen, but I am still getting the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and I solved it by mapping the endpoint on Router (apikit:config).
Then I figured out the name set to the router was different on the endpoint flow, like:

- Flow name: get:(userId):api-config
- Router name: users-api-config

Fixing the name on flow or mapping the method on router solve this problem

Comment: You saved my life!! I spent almost 2 hours on it, tried a lot of things on RAML. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This was my problem as well.   What an unintuitive way of handling that.

Comment: If this answer isn't clear, see jstarek's answer.  It talks about the same root cause.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue due to a name mismatch on my router and application-interface.
If you're using an application interface as a reference for all flows in your application, make sure that you're using same naming on the router config and each endpoint referred on the interface. Something like...

```
<apikit:router doc:name="APIkit Router" config-ref="api-config" />
```

for your router and

```
<flow name="get:\users:api-config"
```

on your interface.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not setting the Content-Type header to `application/json` and the API implementation is expecting it.

Comment: Thanks for editing my question. I'm not explicitly setting it for my GET request as I thought it only needs to be set for POST and PUT?

Comment: maybe it is complaining that it didn't got one, not that it has to specifically something.

Answer (score 0):

Hello try to include a json example instead a raml example:

!include examples/searchExample.raml convert it to include json example.

!include examples/searchExample.json

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this error by renaming the endpoint generated by the apiKit.

Original Flow Name:

```
get:\worker**:application\json:**prueba-sapi-config
```

Revised Flow Name:

```
get:\worker:cs-prueba-sapi-config
```

With this adjustment, it is no longer necessary to specify the Content-Type.

Comment: Please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).

Comment: @suchislife: 
Please do not translate questions/answers for the OP. They need to be able to respond to feedback, and if they cannot themselves translate a question/answer we cannot be certain that they can understand any feedback provided (by comments, answers, or Help Center content). See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/2275490